# Why is resizing a vector faster than reserve and push_back?

Tags: c++, vector

I was doing some quick benchmark tests involving a `std:vector`. I start with a relatively small vector of 100 ints and call various methods for filling it with 1,000,000 ints. Most of my functions involve clearing the elements and adding the elements again or creating a new vector and moving or swapping it with the original vector. I also have a function that just resizes the vector and overwrites the elements.

You can see the functions in the code below. What's interesting is that resizing the vector and overwriting the elements is by far quickest. I thought that reserving the memory before pushing the elements would improve performance.

I know that `std::vector::resize()` will resize the vector to contain the new count. According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize):

> If the current size is less than count, additional elements are
>   appended and initialized with copies of value.

`resize()` should be constructing 100 less ints than the other functions. So I'm surprised by the difference in speed. I thought `resize()` would allocate and initialize the new elements while reserve would just allocate the memory.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

constexpr int InitialSize = 100;
constexpr int NewSize = 1000000;

void overwrite(std::vector<int>& v)
{
  v.resize(NewSize);
  for (int i = 0; i < NewSize; ++i)
  {
      v[i] = i;
  }
}

void clear(std::vector<int>& v)
{
    v.clear();
    v.reserve(NewSize);
    for (int i = 0; i < NewSize; ++i)
    {
        v.push_back(i);
    }
}

void swap(std::vector<int> &v)
{
    std::vector<int> vnew;
    vnew.reserve(NewSize);
    for (int i = 0; i < NewSize; ++i)
    {
        vnew.push_back(i);
    }
    v.swap(vnew);
}

void move(std::vector<int> &v)
{
    std::vector<int> vnew;
    vnew.reserve(NewSize);
    for (int i = 0; i < NewSize; ++i)
    {
        vnew.push_back(i);
    }
    v = std::move(vnew);
}


int main()
{
    {
        std::vector<int> v(InitialSize);
        std::iota(v.begin(), v.end(), 1);
        auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        move(v);
        auto finish = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli> elapsed = finish - start;
        std::cout << "Move - elapsed time: " << elapsed.count() << " ms" << std::endl;
    }

    {
        std::vector<int> v(InitialSize);
        std::iota(v.begin(), v.end(), 1);
        auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        clear(v);
        auto finish = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli> elapsed = finish - start;
        std::cout << "Clear - elapsed time: " << elapsed.count() << " ms" << std::endl;
    }

    {
        std::vector<int> v(InitialSize);
        std::iota(v.begin(), v.end(), 1);
        auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        swap(v);
        auto finish = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli> elapsed = finish - start;
        std::cout << "Swap - elapsed time: " << elapsed.count() << " ms" << std::endl;
    }

    {
        std::vector<int> v(InitialSize);
        std::iota(v.begin(), v.end(), 1);
        auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        overwrite(v);
        auto finish = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli> elapsed = finish - start;
        std::cout << "Overwrite - elapsed time: " << elapsed.count() << " ms" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Move - elapsed time: 14.6284 ms
Clear - elapsed time: 17.5072 ms
Swap - elapsed time: 12.9111 ms
Overwrite - elapsed time: 5.19079 ms
```

[LIVE](https://godbolt.org/z/M_FrTv)

Quick Bench [results](http://quick-bench.com/8q-Ea_uNHZjxMcGx0zh0UAhP7nc).

Can someone explain what's going on here?

Comment: It doesn't have to update its size member variable if you've resized first. That could have a minor effect.

Comment: `resize` can use some `avx` optimized `memset` to initialize members more efficiently and batched, while `push_back` will initialize them one by one.

Comment: I don't see any compilation flags. Is it optimized by default on godbolt?

Comment: You did compile with optimizations on, right?  (ala `-O3`) ?

Comment: In addition to compilation flags, if you move the overwrtite test as first one, results change so that overwrite is the slower. I guess this benchmark is not really usable.

Comment: For each test function, move, overwrite, clear, and swap.  Instead of assigning `i` in each iteration, assign `rand()`. You'll find the that the metrics of each test case are about the same, not consistently showing the same winner, and all within a margin of error of each other. https://imgur.com/a/PS7SPoX

Comment: You are only testing `int`. A non-trivial type will trigger different optimisation paths and yield wildly different results, I suspect. Also, *always* repeat your timing experiments manifold to gain confidence in the results. As a rule of thumb you shouldn't repeat the experiment less than 20 times. And you should pre-heat the test as suggested by other comments here.

Comment: @selbie Even with optimisation turned off the results are the same. Overwrite is the quickest. I've updated the question with the results from Quick C++ Benchmarks.

Comment: @selbie I tested using `rand()` and even then `overwrite()` is the fastest.

Comment: @selbie No, they didn't. With all optimizations on, execution time drops to about 0.4 seconds.I also tinkered with `#pragma GCC unroll 20000` at home; after 5 or more minutes of compilation (on a somewhat oldish mobile i7) gcc produced an 800 MB executable which did not run any faster than the one with just 10 or 20 unrolls.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

push_back is costlier operation than index based access even if allocation has been taken care of before hand by reserve.

1. push_back will need to take care of end pointer so that vector size can be computed correctly
2. push_back will check for realloaction need. Essentially a branch prediction.
3. push_back will cause copy (or move) of value to be pushed back. In case of int, it shouldn't cause performance difference.

If you see assembly conversion (Taken from godbolt link given in question), index operation is non branching sequence of few moves and shift operation while push_back is much more involved. In long running loop (1000000 in given example), this difference will matter. Compiler optimization level can definitely impact the difference.

For index operator []

```
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp, rsp
    mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rdi
    mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-16], rsi
    mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
    mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rax]
    mov     rdx, QWORD PTR [rbp-16]
    sal     rdx, 2
    add     rax, rdx
    pop     rbp
    ret
```

For push_back

```
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp, rsp
    sub     rsp, 16
    mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rdi
    mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-16], rsi
    mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
    mov     rdx, QWORD PTR [rax+8]
    mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
    mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rax+16]
    cmp     rdx, rax
    je      .L73
    mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8] // When allocation is not needed
    mov     rcx, QWORD PTR [rax+8]
    mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
    mov     rdx, QWORD PTR [rbp-16]
    mov     rsi, rcx
    mov     rdi, rax
    call    void std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<int> >::construct<int, int const&>(std::allocator<int>&, int*, int const&)
    mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
    mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rax+8]
    lea     rdx, [rax+4]
    mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
    mov     QWORD PTR [rax+8], rdx
    jmp     .L75
.L73:   // When allocation is needed
    mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
    mov     rdi, rax
    call    std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::end()
    mov     rcx, rax
    mov     rdx, QWORD PTR [rbp-16]
    mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
    mov     rsi, rcx
    mov     rdi, rax
.L75:
    nop
    leave
    ret
```

Answer (score 2):

> Can someone explain what's going here?

`overwrite` is fundamentally different than the others, because you never call `push_back` which has to check for resize which makes the loop way more complex.

The other three are basically equivalent (minus constant time differences) and will perform differently depending on optimizations, how good the compiler does its job and the standard library implementation.

If you are very lucky, the optimizer may be able to see that the resizing will never happen and behave like `overwrite`.

Comment: Yes. `push_back()` does have to check size < capacity, otherwise do a reallocation. This is the main difference between `overwrite()` and the other methods. I was trying to avoid the reallocation by setting the capacity beforehand. Yet I would have thought the size check would have been a minor difference.

Comment: @jignatius The point is that even if the reallocation does not happen at runtime, the optimizer still sees all the code that handles that and may not be able to simplify the loop into the equivalent of `overwrite`'s trivial loop. And if the optimizer doesn't arrive at the simplified loop. then it cannot apply the rest of the optimizations either.

Comment: Even if branch prediction is perfect resp. optimized away `push_back()` in case of an int essentially involves *two* assignments, i.e. should be roughly **twice as expensive** in the case of an int: It needs to update the end pointer (or size member)! (Of course a compiler could optimize that away as well; it could actually not do anything much at all except printing the time, since none of all the data shuffled around has an observable effect. The trouble with benchmarks.)